# Does SQL Server Compact not support keywords 'Foreign Key References' in Create Table or am I making a mistake?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I keep getting errors using Sql Compact. I have seen that it is possible to create table constraints in compact edition as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827/how-do-you-create-a-foreign-key-relationship-in-a-sql-server-ce-compact-edition). And according to the documents found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx) it provides "Full referential integrity with cascading deletes and updates". So am I really not allowed to do the following or am I making a mistake? I keep getting complaints from sql server compact edition that the constaint is not valid, though it works fine on express edition.

CREATE TABLE [A] (AKey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE [B] (AKey int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES A(AKey));

Comment: Looks like a year and a half after posting this a munch better answer has come along by psur. Haven't tested it, but if that works, terrific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it works on express edition I will take it that I am not making a mistake. This gives the desired effect, with cascading thrown in, on compact edition.

```
CREATE TABLE [A] (AKey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);  
CREATE TABLE [B] (AKey int NOT NULL);  
ALTER TABLE [B] ADD CONSTRAINT references_a FOREIGN KEY (AKey) REFERENCES A(AKey)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 3):

On Compact Edition you shouldn't write `FOREIGN KEY` keyword, you should omit it and start defining foreign key constraint from `REFERENCES` keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173393(v=sql.100).aspx

So in your case you should write:

```
CREATE TABLE [A] (AKey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE [B] (AKey int NOT NULL REFERENCES A(AKey));
```

And no `ALTER` is needed!

Comment: i spent a painful two hours trying to use Foreign Key References A(AKey). Any idea why they made it that way?